# How to replace every 2nd line sed

Tags: grep, sed, awk, paste, tr

How to replace every 2nd line of a text file with another text file list of lines.
Example:
cat filea.txt
I love Pink
I love Blue
I love Dogs
I love MOMO

cat bileb.txt
I hate yello
I hate white
I hate rats
I hate pigs

Now I need the output as
I love Pink
I hate yello
I love Dogs
I hate rats

textbile b should replace the every 2nd line of text filea without appending it. How can we do that using -i with sed or awk.

I tried to do that using paste comand that dosen't replace it appends.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed, you can use the `R` command:

> ```
>    R filename
>           Append  a line read from filename.  Each invocation of the command 
>           reads a line from the file.  This is a GNU extension.
> ```

So

```
$ sed 'R fileb.txt' filea.txt
I love Pink
I hate yello
I love Blue
I hate white
I love Dogs
I hate rats
I love MOMO
I hate pigs
```

Combined with `d` to delete the original line:

```
$ sed -e '2~2{R fileb.txt' -e 'd;}' filea.txt
I love Pink
I hate yello
I love Dogs
I hate white
```

If you want to replace every 2nd line of filea.txt with every 2nd line of fileb.txt, then:

```
$ sed '2~2d' fileb.txt | sed -e '2~2{R /dev/stdin' -e 'd;}' filea.txt
I love Pink
I hate yello
I love Dogs
I hate rats
```

---

Alternatively, use `paste` to join lines of the files side-by-side, then pipe to `sed` to change the default tab delimiters to newlines on only the odd lines:

```
$ paste filea.txt fileb.txt | sed -n '1~2s/\t/\n/p'
I love Pink
I hate yello
I love Dogs
I hate rats
```

Obviously this won't work if the original filea.txt may contain tab characters.

Since you also tagged your question `awk`, you could also consider something like

```
awk '{getline x < "fileb.txt"} NR%2 {print; print x}' filea.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked for me.

Comment: @Pooja Jha can you mark the answer as helpful?